# A basic question on measure theory, compact set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is it possible that a subset of $\Bbb R$ has infinite measure but all the compact subsets of it has zero measure.

Comment: No. Call the set $A$. There is some $n$ so that $\mu(A\cap[-n,n])$ has finite positive measure. There is a compact subset of $A\cap[-n,n]$ with positive measure by the regularity of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: In fact, an arbitrarily large finite positive measure.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Call the set $A$. There is some $n$ such that $\mu\bigl(A\cap[−n,n]\,\bigr)$ has finite positive measure. There is a compact subset of $A\cap[−n,n]$ with positive measure by the [regularity of Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure).